# Possible to prove that a particular trigonometric expression is always positive?

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, trigonometry, optimization

This is a continuation of the an [earlier post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2997034) where the geometric motivation was presented. Here I'd like to ask: is it possible to prove $\Delta > 0$ always?

$$\begin{align} 
\Delta &\equiv \sin(t) \sin\left(r+ (2 \pi -2 r - t)\frac{\epsilon}4 \right) \sin\left( \frac{2 - \epsilon}2 (\pi-r-t)\right) \\
&\quad {} - \frac{2 - \epsilon}2 \sin(r) \sin\left(t-\frac{\epsilon \; t}{4}\right) \sin(r+t)
\end{align}$$
where $$0<r<\frac{\pi}{4} \qquad 0<t<\frac{\pi}{4} \qquad 0<\epsilon <1$$

Some relevant posts include [this one that renders the final form](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3051062) of $\Delta$, which hasn't gotten satisfactory answers.

Comment: What have you tried? where did you get stuck?

Comment: @RoryHector: To repeat a comment I made on [one of your other questions](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3030274/409): It might help if you could provide the context from which this expression arises. There may be a clear geometric reason for it to be positive.

Comment: This intrigues me so I did some numerical exploration. It looks like the infimum is $0$ up to floating point error.

Comment: @RoryHector: There was no indication that the question here had any bearing on the previous question. (So, you might want to link to the previous one to add context.) Also, you should explain the "complicated" nature of the situation *in the question itself", so that it doesn't get lost in comments that people may not read; there's also the advantage that you can add images to help explain what's going on.

Comment: Of course the traditional way to show that something is always positive is to write it as a sum of squares plus a positive constant.

Answer (score 3):

Given
$$0<r<\frac{\pi}{4} \qquad 0<t<\frac{\pi}{4} \qquad 0<\varepsilon <1\tag1$$

Easily to see that 
$$t<\dfrac\pi2,\quad \dfrac{\varepsilon t}4 <\dfrac\pi{16}.$$

At the same time, sine increases in $\left(0,\dfrac\pi2\right).$

Therefore,
$$\begin{align}
&\sin t >\sin\left(t-\dfrac{\varepsilon t}4\right),\\[4pt]
&\Delta > \sin t\left(\sin\left(r+(2 \pi -2 r - t)\frac{\varepsilon}4 \right) \sin\left(\frac{2 - \varepsilon}2 (\pi-r-t)\right) - \frac{2 - \varepsilon}2\sin r\sin(r+t)\right).
\end{align}$$

On the other hand, 
$$\sin\left(\frac{2-\varepsilon}2(\pi-r-t)\right)
= \sin\left((\pi-r-t)-(2\pi-2r-2t)\frac\varepsilon4\right)\\
= \sin\left(r+t+(2\pi-2r-2t)\frac\varepsilon4\right)
= \sin\left(r+t+\dfrac{3\varepsilon t}4+(2\pi-2r-t)\frac\varepsilon4\right).$$
So it is sufficiently to prove inequality $\delta(\varepsilon) >0,$ where
$$\delta(\varepsilon) = \sin(r+\varepsilon\varphi)\sin\left(r+t+\dfrac{3\varepsilon t}4+\varepsilon\varphi\right) - \frac{2 - \varepsilon}2 \sin(r)\sin(r+t),\tag2$$
$$\varphi = \dfrac{2\pi-2r-t}4 \in\left(\dfrac{5\pi}{16},\dfrac\pi2\right),\quad \dfrac{3\varepsilon t}4 <\dfrac{3\pi}{16},\tag3$$
under the conditions $(1).$

Really,
$$\delta(\varepsilon) = \sin(r+\varepsilon\varphi)\sin\left(r+t+\dfrac{3\varepsilon t}4 +\varepsilon\varphi\right) - \frac{2 - \varepsilon}2 \sin(r)\sin(r+t)\\
 = \frac12\left(\cos\left(t+\dfrac{3\varepsilon t}4\right) - \cos\left(2r+t+\dfrac{3\varepsilon t}4+2\varepsilon\varphi\right)- \cos(t) + \cos(2r+t) +\varepsilon\sin(r)\sin(r+t)\right)\\
 = \frac12\left(\cos\left(t+\dfrac{3\varepsilon t}4\right) - \cos(t) - \cos\left(2r+t+\dfrac{3\varepsilon t}4+2\varepsilon\varphi\right) + \cos(2r+t) +\varepsilon\sin(r)\sin(r+t)\right)\\
 =  -\sin\dfrac{3\varepsilon t}8 \sin\left(t+\dfrac{3\varepsilon t}8\right) + \sin\left(\varepsilon\varphi+\dfrac{3\varepsilon t}8\right) \sin\left(2r+t+\varepsilon\varphi+\dfrac{3\varepsilon t}8\right) + \dfrac\varepsilon2\sin(r)\sin(r+t).$$
Taking in account that
$$\varepsilon < 1 < 1+\dfrac{\pi-2r-2t}{\pi-r+t} = 2-\dfrac{r+3t}{\pi-r+t},\tag4$$
one can get
$$t+\dfrac{3\varepsilon t}8 < t+\dfrac{3\varepsilon t}8+2r +\varepsilon\varphi, \tag5$$
$$ t+\dfrac{3\varepsilon t}8+2r+\varepsilon\varphi = \pi-t-\dfrac{3\varepsilon t}8-\pi+2t+\dfrac{3\varepsilon t}4+2r+\varepsilon\dfrac{2\pi-2r-t}4\\
= \pi-t-\dfrac{3\varepsilon t}8-\pi+2t+2r + \varepsilon\dfrac{\pi-r+t}2\\
< \pi-t-\dfrac{3\varepsilon t}8-\pi+2t+2r
 + \left(2-\dfrac{r+3t}{\pi-r+t}\right)\dfrac{\pi-r+t}2\\
= \pi-t-\dfrac{3\varepsilon t}8-\pi+2t+2r + \pi-r+t -r- 3t 
= \pi-t-\dfrac{3\varepsilon t}8,$$
$$ t+\dfrac{3\varepsilon t}8+2r+\varepsilon\varphi 
< \pi-t-\dfrac{3\varepsilon t}8.\tag6$$
From $(5)-(6)$ should
$$\sin\left(t+\dfrac{\varepsilon t}8+2r+\varepsilon\varphi\right) > \sin\left(t+\dfrac{\varepsilon t}8\right),$$
so
$$\delta(\varepsilon) = \sin\left(\dfrac{\varepsilon t}8+\varepsilon\varphi\right) \sin\left(t+\dfrac{\varepsilon t}8+2r+\varepsilon\varphi\right) - \sin\dfrac{\varepsilon t}8 \sin\left(t+\dfrac{\varepsilon t}8\right) + \dfrac\varepsilon2\sin(r)\sin(r+t) > 0.$$

$\mathbf{Proved.}$

Comment: Early on you say it is easy to see that $\frac{2-\epsilon}{2} (\pi - r- t) < \frac{\pi}{2}$. Can you explain how you can say that? I think its clear that $\frac{2-\epsilon}{2} (\pi - r- t) < \pi$ but that's it

Comment: @RoryHector Thanks! Fixed.

Comment: @RoryHector What about updated varant?

Comment: I didn't check it as an answer because it isn't true that $\sin\Big(\frac{2-\epsilon}{2}(\pi - r -t)\Big) = \sin\Big((\pi - r - t) - (2 \pi - 2 r) \frac{\epsilon}{4}\Big)$

Comment: @RoryHector Just fixed. Thanks.